# Validación de datos en C++ con isdigit, isalpha e isspace

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Quisiera validar campos en los cuales solo se tendrían que permitir valores numéricos o de caracteres, investigando un poco veo que hay funciones que permiten evaluar el dato que se introduce y dependiendo de la función a la que hemos declarado permitir el ingreso o no de dicho dato, las funciones que he investigado son: isdigit (para dígitos), isalpha (para caracteres), isspace (espacios en blancos).
Por ahora he intentado trabajar solo con isalpha para permitir solo caracteres y para ello me he guiado de videotutoriales y así poder construir el siguiente código.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int validar_palabra(char palabra[]);

int main(){

char palabra[20];
int x;
do{
    cout<<"Ingresa una palabra:\n ";
    cin>>palabra;

    x=validar_palabra(palabra);
}while(x==0);

cout<<"Tu entrada es valida\n";



return 0;
system("pause");
}
int validar_palabra(char palabra[]){
int i;

for(i=0; i<strlen(palabra); i++){

    if(!(isalpha(palabra[i]))){

        cout<<"Tu entrada de datos no es permitida\n";
        system("pause");
        return 0;


    }

}
return 1;
}
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Esta es la manera mas eficaz de utilizar (en este caso) la función isalpha o hay alguna otra forma de poder aplicarla de manera aun mas comoda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¿Es la manera más eficaz de utilizar la función isalpha? Pues si, la verdad.  Dado que no hay funciones que automáticamente se apliquen a toda la palabra
la forma más común es hacerlo carácter por carácter tal como lo estás haciendo.

A lo que si se le pueden hacer anotaciones es al uso del lenguaje. En concreto, el uso de arreglos para almacenar cadenas está desaconsejado ya que se pueden desbordar (el usuario puede ingresar una palabra de más de 20 caracteres). Lo mejor en este caso es usar la clase string que reservan la memoria necesaria cuando se lee una cadena.  Para usar el objeto string tiene que incluir la cabecera del mismo nombre:

```
#include <string>
```

Los string se declaran simplemente con la palabra "string" y el nombre de la variable sin necesidad de decir el número de elementos y se leen de igual forma que los arreglos de caracteres.

```
string palabra; // Declara un string llamado palabra
cin >> palabra; // Lee del teclado y almacena en la cadena palabra
```

Ahora bien, ya que estés usando string en lugar de arreglos de caracteres también te puedes dar el lujo de usar un ciclo for-each en lugar de un for normal. El ciclo for-each recorre cada elemento de un contenedor mediante la siguiente sintaxis:

```
for (tipo elem : contenedor) {
    acciones
}
```

Tu función podría pasar a ser:

```
for (char caracter : palabra) {
    if (!isalpha(caracter)) {
        cout << "Tu entrada de datos no es permitida\n";
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Nota: El ciclo for-each es relativamente nuevo. Requiere indicarle al compilador que se van a usar características recientes del lenguaje.  En el caso de Dev-C++, tienes que ir a herramientas, opciones del copilador y palomear el recuadro que dice algo como: "pasar las siguientes opciones al compilador". Luego escribir en la primer área de escritura: "-std=c++11" y finalmente aceptar.

Segundo, aunque se puede usar enteros para expresar condiciones booleanas, hay un tipo de dato especial para tal fin que es el tipo bool. Usar el tipo de dato adecuado deja claras tus intenciones para otras personas que lean tu código. El prototipo de la función pasaría a ser:

```
bool validar_palabra(string palabra);
```

Por último, podrías incluso ahorrarte la función si aplicas alguna de las funciones plantilla que hay en la cabecera "algorithm".  En concreto, la función que te serviría es all_of que sirve para saber si todos elementos de un contenedor cumplen una determinada condición.  La forma de usarla sería la siguiente:

```
bool todos_cumplen = all_of(palabra.begin(), palabra.end(), ::isalpha);
```

Un código aplicando esa función sería el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>   // cin y cout
#include <string>     // string
#include <algorithm>  // all_of
#include <cstdlib>    // system
#include <cctype>     // isalpha
using namespace std;

int main() {
    bool valida;
    string palabra;

    do {
        cin >> palabra;

        // Se comprueba que todos los caracteres cumplan isalpha
        valida = all_of(palabra.begin(), palabra.end(), ::isalpha);

        if (!valida) {
            cout << "Tu entrada de datos no es permitida" << endl;
            system("pause");
        }
    } while (!valida);

    cout << "Tu entrada es válida" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Iba a responder a la pregunta creyendo que podía aportar algo más que esta respuesta, pero no me es posible. Buen trabajo Saul.

Comment: Gracias. He releído la publicación tras tu mensaje y me di cuenta de que el nombre de la cabecera algorithm no se veia porque lo puse entre paréntesis angulares.